# How to print time in kernel source?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm a newbie of Linux.

I'm modifying kernel/sys.c in Linux kernel source.

To see the fluctuation of system calls, I want to modify this source to print the time.

But I think I can use printf in kernel source.

How can I print time????

Comment: You always can use `perf` tool which is dedicated for such thing like tracing and monitoring stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use `printk` (see http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3 for example) and to enable `PRINTK_TIMES` feature, so you'll get the output in form of

```
[8804849.737776] Kernel BUG at fs/nfs/file.c:321
```

Where these two numbers is the number of seconds and microseconds since system booted.

You can enable this in several ways:

1. You can define `CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME` kernel config option
2. At boot time, passing `printk.time=1`
3. At runtime, issuing `# echo 1 > /sys/module/printk/parameters/time`

Some resources:

- https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/PrintkTimestampMeaning
- http://elinux.org/Printk_Times